# Why Ant on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ant

I am wondering what exactly I can do on Ant-on-Eclipse that I can't on Eclipse? From what I know, Eclipse provides all compile/build facilities and runs XML scripts. I have Tomcat installed on Eclipse. why should I go for Ant on top of these?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found impossible to develop apps that need to use APK Expansion files with Eclipse.  Maybe that's fixed in Eclipse now but I had to give up using Eclipse and found that using Ant wasn't so bad and kind of nice. And don't think I'll go back.

Comment: I feel this question is fair and should not be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is an Integrated **Development** Environment and at that it is just one of several. Many people enjoy using other development tools. Larger projects might even use Jenkins or another form of continuous integration with automated builds. Ant and Maven just happen to be the most popular tools for building Java and you should use one of them to keep your project from requiring eclipse to build and deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Ant is build tool to make life easy for solving tasks like

- Compiling
- Building
- Packaging
- Testing
- Deploying
- Generating reports
- and many more

Now of course you can use it on a simple console but using it with eclipse IDE is a fun as you can manage/edit/write scripts there easily and it prints logs in more readable format.

Answer (score 1):

One of my favourite graduate interview questions is "how do you send programs to your users". This enables insight into how aware a developer is to the needs for proper packaging of software and management of 3rd party dependencies.

I don't mean to sound insulting, but I find it amazing the number of students who only use Eclipse to compile their code and distribute their applications as a zip archive of the class files folder. Worse still a zip of the source code, expecting their users to also use Eclipse to compile and run their code....

Here's the reality. There are good technical reasons why Java code needs to be compiled and packaged as jars/wars/etc. An effective Java developer needs to understand  how this process works.

However.... Looking at this problem from the perspective of a newcomer... Is this software development process old fashioned? I'm not suggesting dumping Java in favour of script technologies like [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) and [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/). What I'm pointing out is that perhaps the mechanics of compile, package and distribute are best done by a machine. Emerging cloud PAAS technologies like [Cloud Foundry](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/) and [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/) are starting to challenge my brain in interesting ways.

In conclusion, if you're new to Java install the [Maven Eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html). You'll gain the advantages of a proper build tool and it will integrate neatly into your Eclipse environment.